# ProperyChanged event always null - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged

I have seen some answers related to this issue but neither quite resembled this scenario I have. I have a settings class and when one of the properties is updated I want another class to be notified. The event is being fired but however its handler is always null.

Can somebody help me understand what is wrong?

```
class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Our settings
    ApplicationDataContainer settings ;

    // The key names of our settings
    const string CheckBoxSettingKeyName = "CheckBoxSetting";
    const string ComboBoxSettingKeyName = "ComboBoxSetting";

    // The default value of our settings
    const bool CheckBoxSettingDefault = true;
    private int ComboBoxSettingDefault = 0;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public AppSettings()
    {
        settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;
        // If the key exists
        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (settings.Values[Key] != value)
            {
                // Store the new value
                settings.Values[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise create the key.
        else
        {
            settings.Values.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        return valueChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current value of the setting, or if it is not found, set the 
    /// setting to the default setting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="Key"></param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
    {
        T value;
        // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
        if (settings.Values.ContainsKey(Key))
        {
            value = (T)settings.Values[Key];
        }
        // Otherwise, use the default value.
        else
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
    }

    /// Property to get and set a ComboBox Setting Key.

    public int ComboBoxSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<int>(ComboBoxSettingKeyName, ComboBoxSettingDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(ComboBoxSettingKeyName, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "... but however its handler is always null."? When "if (PropertyChanged != null)" results in false this means that no other code has attached itself to the event currently. Do you have some "+=" in your code?

Comment: yes I have in another class settings.PropertyChanged += Settings_PropertyChanged;     - maybe I am doing it the wrong way though.

Comment: Have you ensured, that the +=-call happens before you hit the breakpoint which shows you that the handler is null?

Comment: but I am listening to this event somewhere else. so the event listener can only be "fired" after the event notifies there was a change. the problem is since  if(PropertyChanged != null) is always false, there is no notification PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));   therefore there is no += listener being fired. Am I correct on this?

Answer (score 1):

I removed some of your code and created a new console application. Then I changed to Program class to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create instance
            var settings = new AppSettings();
            // subscribe for the event as soon as you can
            settings.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Property {0} has changed", e.PropertyName);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start test");
            Console.ReadKey();
            // change the value
            settings.ComboBoxSettings = 10;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int _comboBoxSettings;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int ComboBoxSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return _comboBoxSettings;
            }
            set
            {
                _comboBoxSettings = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    #endregion
}
```

}

If you past this into a fresh console application it works.

Comment: thanks it seems now I know what I was doing wrong because of your explanation/help. I was listening to the event in a class that was being instantiated somewhere else and then destroyed, of course it would always be null if I tried to capture the event... thanks. I need to refactor the code if I want to do this with INotifyPropertyChanged interface